# Dynamic Programming-Find the maximum possible sum in a 2D matrix

Tags: dynamic-programming

Find the maximum possible sum in a 2D matrix such that if element[i][j] is selected then the next element cannot be selected again from the same ith row or jth column.

example 3*3 matrix

6.0   7.0        6.0 
 4.5      6.0       6.75
 
 6.0      5.0       9.0

Here maximum sum is 21 because 6.0(1st row)+6.0(2nd row)+9.0(3rd row)=21
We cannot select 7.0(1st row)+6.75(2nd row)+9.0(3rd row) because 6.75 and 9.0 lie in the same column.

I understand its a dynamic programming problem. What would be an algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that you cannot re-use a column or row, your sums are going to be diagonal lines. Here is my first stab at an algorithm (in pseudocode):

```
our largest known sum is 0.

for(0 to columncount-1)
    sum element[0][column]'s diagonal (i.e. 6.0 + 6.0 + 9.0, then 7.0 + 6.75, then 6.0)
    if it's greater than our largest sum, it becomes the largest sum and we track those elements.
for(1 to rowcount-1)
    sum element[row][0]'s diagonal (i.e. 4.5 + 5.0, then 6.0)
    if it's greater than our largest sum, it becomes the largest sum and we track those elements.
```

Then you need to repeat going the other way (i.e. right-left, then top-bottom).

I don't know if that makes sense, but that algorithm will give you the largest combination, for any rectangular matrix.

Comment: So if we have a rectangular matrix lets say 3 by 5. In this case there is a possibility that we max sum could be element[0][3]+element[1][0]+element[2][4]. These elements are not diagonal elements here.

Comment: Ah, true, you got me. I'll have to take a second pass at it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is essentially an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) which can be solved by the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). You just need to convert the maximum goal to a minimum goal by either subtract all elements from the global maximum or negate them.